# Using 1 thread in multithreading is faster than singlethreading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, conways-game-of-life

I'm improving my code based on comments and answer on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61393606/openmp-with-game-of-life-visualization-using-sfml)
As a result, serial processing for game of life works like below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                int neighbor = countNeighbors(gamefieldSerial, i, j, width, height);

                if (gamefieldSerial[i][j] == DEAD) {
                    if (neighbor == 3) {
                        gamefieldBuffer[i][j] = LIVE;
                    }
                }
                else if (gamefieldSerial[i][j] == LIVE) {
                    if (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3) {
                        gamefieldBuffer[i][j] = DEAD;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        copyField(gamefieldBuffer, gamefieldSerial, width, height);
```

`countNeighbors()` just counts LIVE cells around current(which is gamefieldSerial[i][j]) cell and return. `int** gamefieldBuffer` for writing new generation of gamefield and `copyField()` to apply it(*Separate the old state from the new state*, It was a lot of help).

And in parallel processing it goes like below(For example, my field is 512*512).
My thought is each thread(4) takes quarter of field(`gamefieldParallel`) and use `gamefieldBuffer1, gamefieldBuffer2, gamefieldBuffer3, gamefieldBuffer4`(which is exact same use of `gamefieldBuffer`) to write new generation of quarter of gamefield and apply it with for-loop.

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
        {
#pragma omp sections firstprivate(gamefieldParallel)
            {
#pragma omp section
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
                            int neighbor = countNeighbors(gamefieldParallel, i, j, width, height);

                            if (gamefieldParallel[i][j] == DEAD) {
                                if (neighbor == 3) {
                                    gamefieldBuffer1[i][j] = LIVE;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (gamefieldParallel[i][j] == LIVE) {
                                if (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3) {
                                    gamefieldBuffer1[i][j] = DEAD;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

#pragma omp section
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                        for (int j = 256; j < 512; j++) {
                            int neighbor = countNeighbors(gamefieldParallel, i, j, width, height);

                            if (gamefieldParallel[i][j] == DEAD) {
                                if (neighbor == 3) {
                                    gamefieldBuffer2[i][j] = LIVE;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (gamefieldParallel[i][j] == LIVE) {
                                if (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3) {
                                    gamefieldBuffer2[i][j] = DEAD;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

#pragma omp section
                {
                    for (int i = 256; i < 512; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
                            int neighbor = countNeighbors(gamefieldParallel, i, j, width, height);

                            if (gamefieldParallel[i][j] == DEAD) {
                                if (neighbor == 3) {
                                    gamefieldBuffer3[i][j] = LIVE;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (gamefieldParallel[i][j] == LIVE) {
                                if (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3) {
                                    gamefieldBuffer3[i][j] = DEAD;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

#pragma omp section
                {
                    for (int i = 256; i < 512; i++) {
                        for (int j = 256; j < 512; j++) {
                            int neighbor = countNeighbors(gamefieldParallel, i, j, width, height);

                            if (gamefieldParallel[i][j] == DEAD) {
                                if (neighbor == 3) {
                                    gamefieldBuffer4[i][j] = LIVE;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (gamefieldParallel[i][j] == LIVE) {
                                if (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3) {
                                    gamefieldBuffer4[i][j] = DEAD;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } // end of sections
        } // end of parallel

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
                gamefieldParallel[i][j] = gamefieldBuffer1[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            for (int j = 256; j < 512; j++) {
                gamefieldParallel[i][j] = gamefieldBuffer2[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 256; i < 512; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
                gamefieldParallel[i][j] = gamefieldBuffer3[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 256; i < 512; i++) {
            for (int j = 256; j < 512; j++) {
                gamefieldParallel[i][j] = gamefieldBuffer4[i][j];
            }
        }
```

The reason I implemented like this is I tried to follow these tips.

- Separate the old state from the new state: So I'm using multiple fields.
- Your threads can all happily share the old state (because no-one is changing it during an iteration): firstprivate() to give each thread copy of gamefield.
- Break the work into chunks - one for each thread: So I quartered it.
- Give each thread its own piece of memory to store its results.: That is gamefieldBuffer1, 2, 3, 4.
- Once all threads are finished, have you main thread bring all their results together into one combined new game field.: That is done with for-loop.

And result was positive. I mean definitely it made some speedup for serial and parallel both **but still parallel is slower than serial.** I think there're some error or mistake somewhere but I can't find it.
This is my first problem.

My second question is, when I set parallel region's num_threads() as 1, not 4, why it's faster than serial processing.
[result with 4 thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HBWr.png)
[result with 1 thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AI4Z.png)
With picture above 4 thread is slightly faster than serial, but most of time it's slower than serial.

I thought **using 1 thread in multithreading is equal with singlethreading, but it's not?**
I'm not used to multicore programming(or multithreading? something using openmp.. :p)which is I am learning from school this semester. Maybe I know something wrong, right? Can someone let me know about these?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of threads, this is a great job for offloading onto the GPU via OpenCL or CUDA.

Comment: My app partitions 2D sizes into 1024x1024 chunks, and then has a thread run on that chunk.  (Typically having 110 x 85 chunks.)  I see improvement there.  (My code also has an OpenCL code path, which has even more performance improvement.)

Comment: What is the type of `gamefieldParallel`? If this is a 2D static array using `firstprivate(gamefieldParallel)` can make a costly memory copy. Moreover, your code is likely to be memory-bound. If this is the case, using multiple threads will significantly not help (it can even be slower if you add new memory transfers). So, I advise you to reduce the memory pressure. Additionally, using 2D chunks may not be faster than 1D horizontal chunks (because of cache-misses and false-sharing). Why do you use sections and not `#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)`?

Comment: I used sections because the result of ```#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)``` wasn't very.. positive. I copy & pasted serial processing's nested for-loop to parallel processing with ```#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) num_threads(4)``` and it was slower than serial. So based on comments and answers of my prior question, I decided to use sections.